# requirejs how to setup dependencies files correctly to be able to pass variables between them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I just started using requirejs and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to link up these files. Usually I just include js files in the correct load order.

main.js

```
requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            "jquery": "jquery-3.3.1",
            "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui",
            "dataTables": "DataTables/datatables",
            "toastr": "toastr",
            "ajaxConfiguration": "myScripts/ajaxConfiguration",
            "dataTablesConfiguration": "myScripts/dataTablesConfiguration",
            "jqueryUiConfiguration": "myScripts/jqueryUiConfiguration",
            "updateDatabaseBtn": "myScripts/updateDatabaseBtn"
        },

    });

    require(['jqueryUiConfiguration', 'updateDatabaseBtn'],
        function() {
        });
```

First off, this made sense, as this file depends on jquery-ui and jquery to function. So simply adding these as dependencies was straight forward.

jqueryUiConfiguration.js

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery-ui'],
    function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            $("#updateBtn").button();
        });
    });
```

Second, this one only needs jquery so again adding the dependencies was straight forward.

ajaxConfiguration.js

```
define(['jquery'], function () {

        var updateDatabaseBtnClicked = false;

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
                if (updateDatabaseBtnClicked) {
                    $("#loading").css("display", "block");
                    $("#overlay").css("display", "block");
                }

            });

            $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                $("#loading").css("display", "none");
                $("#overlay").css("display", "none");
                updateDatabaseBtnClicked = false;
            });

        });
    });
```

Again same with this one.

dataTablesConfiguration.js

```
define(['jquery', 'dataTables'],
    function () {
        var $table;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $table = $("#transactionTable").DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                type: "GET",
                ajax: {
                    url: "DataService.svc/GetDataAsJsonObjects",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                "columns": [
                    { data: "CustomerName" },
                    { data: "CompanyName" },
                    { data: "CurrentBalance" }
                ]
            });
        });
    });
```

However this is the file which actually needs to use code within 
 dataTablesConfiguration.js and ajaxConfiguration.js, as well as some methods from toastr.js, I am not quite sure how to link them together as they need to access the variables from these files

updateDatabaseBtn.js

```
define(['dataTablesConfiguration', 'ajaxConfiguration', 'toastr'], // this is not right
    function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#updateBtn").click(function() {

                updateDatabaseBtnClicked = true;

                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "myApi",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    })
                    .done(function() {
                        $table.ajax.reload();
                        toastr.success("Database updated");
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        toastr.error("Something unexpected happened");
                    });
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass as callback parameters and access module inside the another module

for example

```
    define(['dataTablesConfiguration', 'ajaxConfiguration', 'toastr'], 
            function(dataTablesConfiguration,ajaxConfiguration,toastr) {
              toastr.success("Database updated");

 }
```

to provide correct order from config file you can use sim config file.
for example.

```
"shim": {
    "bootstrap-responsive": {
        "deps": [ "bootstrap", "respond" ],
        "exports": "bootstrap-responsive"
    },
    "komapping": {
        "deps": [ "knockout" ],
        "exports": "komapping"
    },
    "bootstrap": {
        "deps": [ "jquery" ],
        "exports": "bootstrap"
    },
    "bootstrap-dialog": {
        "deps": [ "bootstrap", "jquery" ],
        "exports": "bootstrap-dialog"
    },
    "jquery-ui": {
        "deps": [ "jquery" ],
        "exports": "$"
    }
}
```